# How to prevent a macro from freezing / turning white the Excel window?

Tags: vba, excel

So at work I am working on a macro/UserForm in Excel for someone. It works great (I think) and does exactly what it needs to do and takes under 1 minute to run, going through ~70k cells and organizing them. Now I was wondering if there was a way to slow it down so that Excel does not go into "Not Responding" mode while it runs. It would just be better so people that need to use the macro don't freak out when it freezes. And it would be best if there was a solution in VBA so people don't have to worry about it and it works perfectly the first time.

**About the Macro**

The data is a bunch of numbers that need to be put in one column, and that the 14 (normally 14) columns before it label each number with dates and other data. All size references and sheet names needs to be from a UserForm so I don't know the name of the sheets or size ahead of time this resulted in some weird code at the beginning of my loop.

Also, if you see anyway to make my code more efficient that would be greatly appreciated!

**The Code**

```
Private Sub UserForm_Initialize()

    'This brings up the data for my dropdown menu to pick a sheet to pull data from
    For i = 1 To Sheets.Count
        combo.AddItem Sheets(i).name
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub OK_Click()

    Unload AutoPivotusrfrm

    'Declaring All of my Variables that are pulled from Userform

    Dim place As Long

    Dim x1 As Integer
    x1 = value1.Value
    Dim x2 As Integer
    x2 = value2.Value
    Dim x3 As Integer
    x3 = value4.Value
    Dim y1 As Integer
    y1 = value3.Value

    Dim copyRange As Variant

    Dim oldname As String
    oldsheetname = combo.Text

    Dim newname As String
    newname = newsheetname.Text

    Sheets.Add.name = newsheetname

    'Labels for section one
    Worksheets(CStr(oldsheetname)).Activate
    copyRange = Range(Cells(x1, x1), Cells(x1 + 1, x3 - 1)).Value
    Worksheets(CStr(newsheetname)).Activate
    Range(Cells(x1, x1), Cells(x1 + 1, x3 - 1)).Value = copyRange
    place = x1 + 2
    x1 = place


    'Looping through the cells copying data
    For i = x1 To x2
    'This was the only way to copy multiple cells at once other ways it would just error
        Worksheets(CStr(oldsheetname)).Activate
        copyRange = Range(Cells(i + 3 - x1, x1 - 2), Cells(i + 3 - x1, x3 - 1)).Value
        Worksheets(CStr(newsheetname)).Activate
        For j = x3 To y1
            Range(Cells(place, 1), Cells(place, x3 - 1)).Value = copyRange
            Cells(place, x3) = Sheets(CStr(oldsheetname)).Cells(1, j)
            Cells(place, x3 + 1) = Sheets(CStr(oldsheetname)).Cells(2, j)
            Cells(place, x3 + 2) = Sheets(CStr(oldsheetname)).Cells(i + 2, j)
            place = place + 1
        Next j
    Next i

End Sub

Private Sub cancel_Click()

    Unload AutoPivotusrfrm

End Sub
```

Comment: look to implement a progress bar in VBA.  There are a lot of examples on google

Comment: Or easier than a progress bar: after each round of the loop, update `Application.StatusBar` with a text of your choice such as "Row x of y"

Answer (score 12, accepted):

As @stuartd mentioned in the comments, `DoEvents` will probably allow the user to interact with Excel while the macro is running, and prevent Excel from becoming unresponsive.

An alternative approach is to **speed up** your code, so that it finishes before the user has reason to believe that it has crashed.  In this vein, here are some suggestions:

1. **Turn off Screen Updating:** It is a lot of work for Excel to render the screen.  You can free those resources to work on what you need done by adding `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` to the beginning of your code, and `Application.ScreenUpdating = True` to the end.
2. **Turn off Calculations:** If you have a lot of formulas running, this can slow down what happens when you place a value into the workbook, as it needs to recalculoate.  My preferred way of dealing with this is to store the current calculation setting, turn off calculations, and then restore the original setting at the end.

```
Dim Calc_Setting as Long
Calc_Setting = Application.Calculation
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
'Your code here
Application.Calculation = Calc_Setting
```

3. **Use Worksheet Variables:** You keep accessing your Worksheets by name.  For repeated access, it should be faster to store that in a variable.  Along with this, don't use `Activate` or `Select`.  Fully reference you calls to `Cells`, so that it accesses the right worksheet.

```
Dim oldsheet as Worksheet, newsheet as Worksheet
Set oldsheet =  Worksheets(CStr(oldsheetname))
Set newsheet =  Worksheets(CStr(newsheetname))
oldsheet.Cells(place, x3) = ...
```

4. **Use Variant Arrays:**  This should speed up your code the most, but also has a *caveat*.  Excel and VBA are slow when they interact.  Within your inner loop, VBA is accessing Excel 7 times.  By pulling those interactions out of the loops, we can achieve a serious performance boost.  The issue is that reading/writing arrays to Excel Ranges is still bound by the 2003 size limits (65536 rows, ...).  If you expect to have more data than this, you will need to do some gymnastics to make it work.

```
Dim inVal as Variant, Output as Variant

inVal = Range(oldsheet.Cells(1,x1-2),oldsheet.Cells(x2+3-x1,y)).Value
redim output(1 to (x2-x1) * (y-x3) + 2, 1 to x3+2)
'These numbers are not tested, you should test.

'Loops to fill output.  This will need to be 1 entry at a time.

newsheet.Cells(x1,x1).Resize(Ubound(output,1), Ubound(output,2)).Value
```

Comment: This answers alot of questions, thanks! I am new to VBA so I was just trying to make it work, you helped me make it fast.

Comment: So i am working on some of the stuff you posted above, It all worked great except for when i started doing Variants. I get error 1004 at this line
`Dim oldsheetValue1 As Variant
    oldsheetValue1 = oldsheet.Range(oldsheet.Cells(i + 3 - x1, x1 - 2), oldsheet.Cells(i + 3 - x1, x3 - 1)).Value`

Comment: I get 'type mismatch' error.  What is Application in Application.Calculation?