# Will Application.ScreenUpdating = False speed up Excel macros with numerous .Select statements?

Tags: vba, excel

I've read that `.Select` statements force Excel to display each of those events on the screen and slow Macros considerably.

I'd like to speed up some old Macros that were written with record Macro methods and have many `.Select` statements.

Would `Application.ScreenUpdating = False` eliminate the time wasted displaying the `.Select` events?

Thanks in advance for any advice.

Comment: You better avoid the often superfluous use of `.select` to optimize performance.

Comment: @pnuts The macro moved much faster and there were literally hundreds of .Select statements it had to plow through.  Is it that simple to fix the time wasted? Or are the .Select statements still wasting time as they operate out of sight? At this point I don't think anyone who uses the macro will complain haha but I'd like to know to grow my skills.

Comment: one way to grow your skills is to eliminate the .select statements from the code

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of curse it would speed up your old Macros,but i would be better to change to code and avoid the `.Select` Statment. Because there is no need for Example to Select a Cell and then write to the Cell. It's more efficent to write directly to the cell.

Take a look at this entrys. They will give you help optimizingyour VBA Code.

[Optimizing VBA macro](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37179525/optimizing-vba-macro/37180251#37180251)

[How to prevent a macro from freezing / turning white the Excel window?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30598699/how-to-prevent-a-macro-from-freezing-turning-white-the-excel-window/30599867#30599867)

[How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)